# How to use exclude-patterns from a file

Tags: awk

I want to use awk to search for pattern in multiple files but exclude some patterns from file

This is the code I have tried

```
BEGIN { print "Begin Processing of various Records"}
/Type.*ABC/ {a=1} /999/{a=0; if (a==1) print a;}
END { print "Process Complete" }
```

Examples:

This is the file example

```
Resources:
  CODE:
    Type: "ABC::DEF::AVC"
    Type: "ABC::DEF::999"
    Type: "ABC::DEF::ZZZ"
```

Now suppose I have file excludes with content

```
999
888
ZZZ
```

Now, I want to display all lines with match first pattern but excludes if any pattern from excludes is found.

Comment: `a=0; if (a==1) print a;` checking if `a` is 1 right after setting it to 0 is nonsense, `a` will never be printed

Comment: in this case grep is simpler: `grep 'Type.*ABC' example | grep -v -F -f excludes`

Comment: AND only the value `0` or `1` would be printed by `print a`, not the values on the line scanned. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter can i print $0 in END block  after checking a ?

Comment: I believe you can, but `$0` will only have the value for the last line processed by your script. I kind of remember that some versions of `awk` don't have `$0` in scope in their `END` blocks, but I am likely wrong, or confusing that with `BEGIN`. .... In the body of your script, you can do `if (a) print $0;` But the `a=0;` thing as mentioned above will have to be dealt with. While I love `awk`, from my experience, I think the dbl-`grep` with `-v -F -f` is the way to go for you stated problem. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter you're right, the value of $0 in the END section is undefined by POSIX so some awks will have it retain the value of the last record read, others will have it as NULL, and others still could do other things with it (but I haven't seen that third option!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk -F'[:"]' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} /Type.*ABC/ && !($(NF-1) in a)' excludes file
    Type: "ABC::DEF::AVC"
```

Answer (score 1):

if your data in 'd' file, try gnu awk:

```
awk '/Type.*ABC/ && $0 !~ /999|888|ZZZ/' d
```